# Playframework 2 - Avoid aggregation of public assets when building dist

Tags: playframework-2.0, packaging, playframework-2.4

When building application with `dist`, is there a way to avoid aggregation of assets in a jar and let these assets in a root "public" folder ?

Comment: The goal is to let the front web server handle all the static resources with the same caching / expiration params

Comment: Do you mean you want to serve the public assets via another server while play handles the dynamic stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static assets are packaged in a `my-app.assets.jar`.

I ended up untaring this jar to the correct location :

```
jar xf my-app.assets.jar
mv ./public ./target_location
```

This way I can let the frontend server manage these assets (adding the good caching headers, gzipping...)